# TeamCity build status remains pass even though there is a failure

Tags: c#, nunit, teamcity, specflow

I have got into a strange issue where Team City build status remains PASS on certain failure.

I have developed an automation framework using SpecFlow and NUnit, and running the tests from Team City10.x. One of my test cases is to compare a string with the UI providing value, there I got some UNICODE character (U+2018 & U+2019) from UI.

> **Example:** 
>   **Expected value given in feature file:** Sample string with 'quotes' 
>   **Actual value coming from UI:** Sample string with ‘quotes’

String comparison is working fine and NUnit marks the test as failure too. As single quotes are mismatching.

But when I check the Team City build status, it remains GREEN only in this case. On the other hand, if there is any other failure, build status is getting changed to RED as expected. Confused with no clue why!

So can someone please help me to understand why this discrepancy?

Comment: What is your automation framework built in? You may be exiting with a 0 when your code completes. If there was an error you need to Exit(1) in order for it to flag the build as broken.

Comment: Yes, I do exit with 1.. For all other failures it works fine, but for this case only it's not working though it's exiting with message `Process exited with code 1`